# Problema com função do javascript usa class

Tags: javascript, html

Então eu tenho uma função no javascript que muda a class de um objeto e depois mais tarde tento procurar esse objeto noutra função com a nova classe , mas tal não se sucede e da me um objeto undefined .. gostaria de saber o que estava a fazer mal se nao fosse muito inconveniente, alem disso também alguém me poderia dar alguma dica sobre , quando uso o localstorage se é possível ir adicionando sempre mais um valor key mais alta que ja la tenho ? Obrigado!

Html:

```
<button id="xs" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function SizeButtonStyle(el) {

   var size = el    
   if(el.id == 'xs'){
      document.getElementById('xs').className = "clicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
   }
   if(el.id == 's'){
      document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('s').className = "clicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
   }
   if(el.id == 'm'){
      document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('m').className = "clicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
   }
   if(el.id == 'l'){
      document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('l').className = "clicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
   }
   if(el.id == 'xl'){
      document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
      document.getElementById('xl').className = "clicked_size_button";
   }
}  

function addToCartClicked(event){
   var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product_name')[0].innerText
   var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText
   var size = document.getElementById('clicked_size_button')[0].innerText
   var info = [product,size,price];
   localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(info)); 
}
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML (ou função) que chama `addToCartClicked`? Queria juntar uma resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou supor que você esta recebendo `undefined` para os botões que acrescentou como código HTML de sua pergunta, isso porque seu código não possui os elementos com as classes `product_name` e `price` que também geram `undefined` se executarmos o código com esta.

Considerando que está se referindo aos botões, o problema é que você está realizando sua pesquisa com o seguinte código:

```
var size = document.getElementById('clicked_size_button')[0].innerText
```

Observe que você está usando a função `getElementById` para procurar seu elemento, mas não existe nenhum botão com o Id em questão, use `getElementsByClassName` para realizar a busca:

```
var size = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked_size_button')[0].innerText
```

Sobre o `localstorage` aconselho abrir uma pergunta específica para isso e abordar em mais detalhes a situação.

Uma observação interessante ressaltada nos comentários é a propriedade [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Essa propriedade retorna uma lista contendo as classes de determinado elemento, além de fornecer acesso a funções de inclusão e remoção de classes dentre outras funcionalidades úteis quando trabalhamos com classes.

Quando sobrescrevemos a propriedade `className` como esta sendo feito em seu código, sobrescrevemos todas as classes deste elemento, note que você pode ter mais de uma classe vinculada a um elemento e querer remover ou incluir apenas uma classe especifica.

Você poderia editar sua função `SizeButtonStyle` para tirar proveito deste recurso, neste caso seu código seria semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
function SizeButtonStyle(el) {
    const lastItem = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked_size_button');
    if (lastItem.length > 0) {
        lastItem[0].classList.add("unclicked_size_button");
        lastItem[0].classList.remove("clicked_size_button");
    }

    el.classList.add("clicked_size_button");
    el.classList.remove("unclicked_size_button");
}
```